# Pass a variable with a function to another variable and return it

Tags: php

So I'm trying to get this done for multiple languages, it's a function that takes a timestamp from mysql and then in turns it into "days ago, one day ago, one year ago, etc"

```
function time_ago($timestamp, $lang) {
  $time_ago = strtotime($timestamp);
  $current_time = time();
  $time_difference = $current_time - $time_ago;
  $seconds = $time_difference;
  $minutes = round($seconds / 60);
  $hours = round($seconds / 3600);
  $days = round($seconds / 86400);
  $weeks = round($seconds / 604800);
  $months = round($seconds / 2629440);
  $years = round($seconds / 31553280);
  if ($seconds <= 60){
    return $lang['time_just_now'];
  } else if ($minutes <= 60){
    if ($minutes == 1){
      return $lang['time_one_minute_ago'];
    } else {
      return $lang['time_minutes_ago'];
    }
  } else if ($hours <= 24){
    if ($hours == 1){
      return $lang['time_one_hour_ago'];
    } else {
      return $lang['time_hours_ago'];
    }
  } else if ($days <= 7){
    if ($days == 1){
      return $lang['time_one_day_ago'];
    } else {
      return $lang['time_days_ago'];
    }
  } elseif($weeks <= 4.3) {
    if ($weeks == 1) {
      return $lang['time_one_week_ago'];
    } else {
      return $lang['time_weeks_ago'];
    }
  } elseif($months <= 12) {
    if ($months == 1) {
      return $lang['time_one_month_ago'];
    } else {
      return $lang['time_months_ago'];
    }
  } else {
    if ($years == 1) {
      return $lang['time_one_year_ago'];
    } else {
      return $lang['time_years_ago'];
    }
  }
}
```

I have a language session based system which takes all the data from an array

```
$lang['time_one_day_ago'] = 'hace un día';
$lang['time_days_ago'] = "hace {$days} días";
```

but how can I pass the variable $days to the $lang array with the function?

**THE SOLUTION**

```
function time_ago($timestamp) {
  global $lang;
  $time_ago = strtotime($timestamp);
  $current_time = time();
  $time_difference = $current_time - $time_ago;
  $seconds = $time_difference;
  $minutes = round($seconds / 60);
  $hours = round($seconds / 3600);
  $days = round($seconds / 86400);
  $weeks = round($seconds / 604800);
  $months = round($seconds / 2629440);
  $years = round($seconds / 31553280);
  if ($seconds <= 60){
    return $lang['time_just_now'];
  } else if ($minutes <= 60) {
    if ($minutes == 1){
      return $lang['time_one_minute_ago'];
    } else {
      return sprintf(_($lang['time_minutes_ago']), $minutes);
    }
  } else if ($hours <= 24){
    if ($hours == 1){
      return $lang['time_one_hour_ago'];
    } else {
      return sprintf(_($lang['time_hours_ago']), $hours);
    }
  } else if ($days <= 7){
    if ($days == 1){
      return $lang['time_one_day_ago'];
    } else {
      return sprintf(_($lang['time_days_ago']), $days);
    }
  } elseif($weeks <= 4.3) {
    if ($weeks == 1) {
      return $lang['time_one_week_ago'];
    } else {
      return sprintf(_($lang['time_weeks_ago']), $weeks);
    }
  } elseif($months <= 12) {
    if ($months == 1) {
      return $lang['time_one_month_ago'];
    } else {
      return sprintf(_($lang['time_months_ago']), $months);
    }
  } else {
    if ($years == 1) {
      return $lang['time_one_year_ago'];
    } else {
      return sprintf(_($lang['time_years_ago']), $years);
    }
  }
}
```

And then in the language file

```
$lang['time_one_year_ago'] = 'hace un año';
$lang['time_years_ago'] = 'hace %s años';
```

Thanks to arkadianriver for the idea!

Comment: There are libraries for internationalization, you should probably use one instead of trying to design this yourself.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar I'll implement the library in another project :)

Comment: The solution you wrote actually won't work with gettext. The gettext function _() accepts only static strings. When you're ready to translate, gettext has an external function that reads your code to find the static strings and uses those as its string values in the message files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is a neat idea, but your case is exactly where it falls apart. Instead of an array, you can use a function, like what [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) does with its `_()` function. A function can process the string, taking into account any positional variables that are passed in the language message file (and you can use sprintf when representing your string and variables in the code itself).

For example, if you use gettext, it's use would be something like:

`return sprintf(_('The time now is %d.'), $timestamp);`

For translations where there are plural forms, you'll want to use ngettext:

`return sprintf(ngettext('%d minute ago.', '%d minutes ago.', $minutes) $minutes);`

Then, you can rearrange the positional parameters however you need to in the POT file that contains the translations of your strings. There are complications of plurals and how Spanish (and English) have two, whereas a language like Russian has at least 3 depending on the number. If you hire in-country translators, they're keenly aware of things like this and are probably familiar with gettext.

If the licensing or production requirements of gettext is something you can't live with, you can probably use a similar principle with a function like `getLangString('my_key_string',array($parm1,$parm2));` and have the function use that key and the value of the provided parameters to determine which strings to fetch from your translated message files. Sorry, I don't have the wherewithall to provide the guts of such a function, but you probably get the idea. It's a pretty complex process taking into account various language rules, which is why there are libraries for such things. I hope this is something to go on. [Have a look at gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), it's pretty cool.

Comment: Thank you so much, It was an easy fix!

Comment: Here's a quick reference from Mozilla about using gettext in PHP: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Localization/gettext

Answer (score 0):

Your `$days` variable is already defined **inside** of your function. As such, it sounds like you simply want to combine a variable with strings on either side.

In this case you're looking for:

```
$lang['time_days_ago'] = "hace $days días";
```

Or:

```
$lang['time_days_ago'] = "hace" . $days . "días";
```

Note that this will only work from **inside** of the function, so if you want to return that assignment, you'll need to make the assignment inside of the function itself:

```
if ($days == 1){
  return $lang['time_days_ago'] = "hace un día";
} else {
  return $lang['time_days_ago'] = "hace" . $days . "días";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried that but it gives me an undefined $days variable because its not set in the array, the array is in a different php file "en.php", "es.php", etc

Comment: Oh I see. You're making the assignment **outside** of the function, based on a global `$lang` variable. What you really should be doing is returning the value already assigned; `$days` only exists inside of the function. So call the function with the timestamp, and **return** the assigned value with `return $lang['time_days_ago'] = "hace" . $days . "días";`.

Comment: I see, but then for different languages it won't work like that because gramar: in english is  "$days ago", in spanish "hace $days días". That's why I return the variable $lang['time_days_ago'];